# How do I create a subset of data where values in two columns are repetitive?

Tags: sql, r

I have a database with `Names`, `Department`, `Rate`, `EmployeeID` and several other fields and I want to create a subset of employees where the dates are repetitive. For example:

```
"Employees" "Department" "Rate" "EmployeeID" "Date"....
Bob          HR            19.5   09151       5/1/2019
Bob          HR            19.5   09151       5/2/2019
Bill         Accounting    20     09152       5/2/2019
Bob          HR            19.5   09151       5/2/2019
John         Accounting    21     09153       5/3/2019
Bill         Accounting    20     09152       5/2/2019
Jake         HR            23     09154       5/5/2019
```

Should return

```
   "Employees" "Department" "Rate" "EmployeeID" "Date"....
        Bob          HR            19.5   09151       5/2/2019
        Bill         Accounting    20     09152       5/2/2019
        Bob          HR            19.5   09151       5/2/2019
        Bill         Accounting    20     09152       5/2/2019
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think this should be easily found by a quick search. https://chartio.com/learn/databases/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table/

Comment: What did you try? Surely, you can research this question to return distinct records.

Answer (score 0):

IN SQL if you have repeated  rows  you can use distinct clause

```
select distinct bNames, Department, Rate, EmployeeID
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution.

```
df_doubled <- df %>% 
  group_by("Employees", "Department", "Rate", "EmployeeID", "Date") %>% 
  count() %>% 
  filter(n > 1) %>% 
  uncount(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table 
where Date in
(select Date from 
(select Date, count(*) c
from table
group by Date
having count(*) > 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery for this purpose:

```
select Employees, Department, Rate, EmployeeID, Date
from yourtable yt1
where 1 < (select count(*) from yourtable yt2 where yt1.Date = yt2.Date);
```